# Python passing parmaeter to DLL

Tags: python-2.7, dll

I am trying to run a python program which accesses a dll.  The original programs are in C and VB which I have been attempting to translate.

At present my problem is in the following hObject parameter of the function:

`hSearch = ctApidll.ctFindFirst(mhctapi, sQuery, "", hObject, 0)`

The hObject is defined in C as a HANDLE, and in VBA as an integer.

When I try to define hObject as a c_type like:
hObject = c_int()
I get no errors but there is no output from the dll.

If I try:
hObject = c_int(1)
The dll gives me output, and also an error:
Windows Error: Exception: access vio;ation writing 0x00000001.

I've tried other variations, even defining hObject as a string.  This doesn't come up with any errors, but in later code, hObject returns as gibberish, rather than a integer values.

Does anyone have a thought on how to correctly define hObject?